# Mono version confusion

Tags: c#, mono, c#-5.0

Looking at the mono-project page I see that the current stable release is 2.10.8. (Released December 19th, 2011). At the same time it says that C#5.0 async support is included? How comes? I believe that the async stuff in C# 5 was released later than December 19th, 2011 ?

So I just want to know if 2.10.8 does support c#5 async, or if I need to use the 3.0.12 beta version to get the C#5 async support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [release notes](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_3.0), async support was first introduced with Mono 3.0, along with a full C# 5.0 compiler. So 2.10.8 won't have this–you need to use version 3.0 or later.

I see [elsewhere online](http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/03/Mono-2-11) that the 2.11 preview release began adding support for async, but I'm not sure if this is still available for download. Presumably, they've added more C# 5.0 features and upped the version number to 3.0, which is now the beta release of interest.

Comment: The Mono guys started to implement async in 2.11, but soon decided to rebrand that as 3.0. Thus, IMHO 2.11=3.0.

Comment: ok thanks, but I guess that since 3.0 still is in beta, then it is not suitable for production code.

Comment: Mono 3.0.x [is supposed to be stable](https://twitter.com/migueldeicaza/status/337302833466593280), despite the beta label.

Comment: Essentially we're calling it "beta" until we get it integrated into our core products, which we are still working on but are getting very close to a release. Once we release those products in another month or so, it should be officially deemed Stable.